# importing AsyncHttpClient sample code in android studio ide

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I am trying to import Andriod [AsyncHttpClient sample code](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient) in to android studio IDE. I tried the import option, In IDE, iam seeing only ".idea" folder. Not able to browse java files.

Answer (score 0):

I tried importing the project you mentioned above but for me it is showing all the files.

In the android studio try "import non android studio project" menu then follow the guidelines.